# .Net regex - positive lookahead not working

Tags: .net, regex, outlook, regex-lookarounds

I have a regex (.Net - System.Text.RegularExpressions) that is meant to match anything within "( )", and it must contain at least one number, one letter and a forward slash "/".  This is what I have come up with so far:

```
(((?=[^\s]*[0-9])(?=[^\s]*[a-zA-Z])(?=[^\s]*[/])))\([0-9a-zA-Z"£$%^&*([\]_+=\-–`{}:@~#';<>?/.,|\\]+\)
```

In testing (used in Outlook 2010 addin, .Net 4.0) this seemed to work fine and would match / not match the below correctly:

Should match:
- (TYR/12/2), (KEN1/1), (KJC/8430-3&4/Greenfield),

Should not match: 
- (2pm-5pm), (HempsonsLive.18295415.v0.1), (HOW121.3)

However, when testing in a production environment (also Outlook 2010) it is wrongly matching strings as per below:

```
(@name="beausdfdmp_prod")
(@name="plosdfgms04")
(@name="boonapbfms03")
(@name="plonapbfms01")
(@name="bfff_pl_server5")
```

I can't yet reproduce these matches in development and so have no idea why in production it is matching them.  If the client production environment is running .Net 3.5 or below, would this have an effect on the regex?

Any other ideas on what could be causing this issue?

Comment: In the lookahead would rather exclude the closing `)` than using `[^\s]*`. What about  something like `\((?=[^)]*\d)(?=[^)]*\/)(?=[^)]*[a-zA-Z])[^)]+\)` [see demo here](https://regex101.com/r/yS2tO0/1).

Comment: Thanks, will test with this a see how it goes

Answer (score 2):

In the lookahead would rather [exclude](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) the closing `)` than using `[^\s]*`. What about

```
\((?=[^)\d]*\d)(?=[^)\/]*\/)[^)]*?[a-zA-Z][^)]*\)
```

After the opening `\(`

- `(?=[^)\d]*\d)` [look ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for one digit
- `(?=[^)\/]*\/)` look ahead for one forward slash
- `[^)]*?[a-zA-Z][^)]*` non `)` containing at least one alpha until the literal closing `\)`
  If no whitespace is allowed, use `[^\s)]*[a-zA-Z][^\s)]*` instead

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dR3bD7/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the pattern less ambiguous and verbose.

If you plan to match parenthesized strings that should contain at least a digit, a letter and a forward slash, you can use

```
\((?=[^()\p{L}]*\p{L})(?=[^()\d]*\d)(?=[^()/]*/)[^()]*\)
```

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c((%3f%3d%5b%5e()%5cp%7bL%7d%5d*%5cp%7bL%7d)(%3f%3d%5b%5e()%5cd%5d*%5cd)(%3f%3d%5b%5e()%2f%5d*%2f)%5b%5e()%5d*%5c)&i=(TYR%2f12%2f2)%2c+(KEN1%2f1)%2c+(KJC%2f8430-3%264%2fGreenfield)%0d%0a(2pm-5pm)%2c+(HempsonsLive.18295415.v0.1)%2c+(HOW121.3)%0d%0a(%40name%3d%22beausdfdmp_prod%22)%0d%0a(%40name%3d%22plosdfgms04%22)%0d%0a(%40name%3d%22boonapbfms03%22)%0d%0a(%40name%3d%22plonapbfms01%22)%0d%0a(%40name%3d%22bfff_pl_server5%22))

The regex matches:

- `\(` - opening round bracket
- `(?=[^()\p{L}]*\p{L})` - there must be a letter inside the parentheses
- `(?=[^()\d]*\d)` - there must be a digit inside `()`
- `(?=[^()/]*/)` - there must be a slash inside `()`
- `[^()]*` - zero or more symbols other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - closing `)`.

If the regex is handled with non-.NET regex engine, you might want to change it to this:

```
[(](?=[^()A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z])(?=[^()0-9]*[0-9])(?=[^()/]*/)[^()]*[)]
```

See [another demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5B(%5D(%3F%3D%5B%5E()A-Za-z%5D*%5BA-Za-z%5D)(%3F%3D%5B%5E()0-9%5D*%5B0-9%5D)(%3F%3D%5B%5E()%2F%5D*%2F)%5B%5E()%5D*%5B)%5D&i=(TYR%2F12%2F2)%2C%20(KEN1%2F1)%2C%20(KJC%2F8430-3%264%2FGreenfield)%0D%0A(2pm-5pm)%2C%20(HempsonsLive.18295415.v0.1)%2C%20(HOW121.3)%0D%0A(%40name%3D%22beausdfdmp_prod%22)%0D%0A(%40name%3D%22plosdfgms04%22)%0D%0A(%40name%3D%22boonapbfms03%22)%0D%0A(%40name%3D%22plonapbfms01%22)%0D%0A(%40name%3D%22bfff_pl_server5%22)). This regex has no escaping that might also be a problem in your case, and `\p{L}` is replaced with ASCII letters `[a-zA-Z]`.